# mistralai - AttributeError: 'ChatMessage' object has no attribute 'model_dump'

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, large-language-model

I am trying to run a Mistral AI's [python client code example](https://docs.mistral.ai/platform/client/#installation) shown below.

```py
from mistralai.client import MistralClient
from mistralai.models.chat_completion import ChatMessage

model = "mistral-tiny"

client = MistralClient(api_key=userdata.get('MISTRAL_API_KEY'))

messages = [
    ChatMessage(role="user", content="What is the best French cheese?")
]

# No streaming
chat_response = client.chat(
    model=model,
    messages=messages,
)
```

I keep getting `AttributeError: 'ChatMessage' object has no attribute 'model_dump'` but there is nothing about this anywhere.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see if you are using `ChatMessage` anywhere else in your notebook.
I would suggest to create a new virtual environment and then try the code.

I can see that `'model_dump'` is available in `ChatMessage`.

I have `mistralai-0.0.12` and `poetry-1.7.1` on my google colab.

```
print('model_dump' in dir(ChatMessage))
#True
```

All the methods in `ChatMessage` are:

```
print(dir(ChatMessage))
#['__abstractmethods__', '__annotations__', '__class__', '__class_getitem__', '__class_vars__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__fields_set__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get_pydantic_core_schema__', '__get_pydantic_json_schema__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__pretty__', '__private_attributes__', '__pydantic_complete__', '__pydantic_core_schema__', '__pydantic_custom_init__', '__pydantic_decorators__', '__pydantic_extra__', '__pydantic_fields_set__', '__pydantic_generic_metadata__', '__pydantic_init_subclass__', '__pydantic_parent_namespace__', '__pydantic_post_init__', '__pydantic_private__', '__pydantic_root_model__', '__pydantic_serializer__', '__pydantic_validator__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__repr_args__', '__repr_name__', '__repr_str__', '__rich_repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__signature__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_abc_impl', '_calculate_keys', '_check_frozen', '_copy_and_set_values', '_get_value', '_iter', 'construct', 'copy', 'dict', 'from_orm', 'json', 'model_computed_fields', 'model_config', 'model_construct', 'model_copy', 'model_dump', 'model_dump_json', 'model_extra', 'model_fields', 'model_fields_set', 'model_json_schema', 'model_parametrized_name', 'model_post_init', 'model_rebuild', 'model_validate', 'model_validate_json', 'model_validate_strings', 'parse_file', 'parse_obj', 'parse_raw', 'schema', 'schema_json', 'update_forward_refs', 'validate']
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Goku - stands with Palestine. This worked for me!